# Search files based on date created in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have this function that I use to read a directory and get files with a specific  search pattern. Is there a way to use a search pattern based on the created date or modified date?

```
public static List<FileInfo> GetFileList(string fileSearchPattern, string rootFolderPath)
{
    DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(rootFolderPath);

    List<DirectoryInfo> dirList = new List<DirectoryInfo>(
        rootDir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    dirList.Add(rootDir);

    List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirList)
    {
        fileList.AddRange(
            dir.GetFiles(fileSearchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
    }

    return fileList;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, but you could filter them quickly with Linq; something like:

```
var files = from c in directoryInfo.GetFiles() 
            where c.CreationTime >somedate
            select c;
```

Comment: Yes it works, the only trouble was i needed to convert the IEnumerable to List but I found it. Thanx

Comment: My concern is that one of our company folders has more than 1 million files so it makes directoryInfo.GetFiles() not responding.

Answer (score 5):

This gives me the files from the last month, for instance:

```
new DirectoryInfo("c:\\Aaron")
    .EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(file =>
        file.CreationTime > DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1));
```

Comment: Thanx i will need this for later use

Answer (score 0):

use can use

```
System.Linq;

var files = directoryInfo.GetFiles().Where(a => a.CreationTime>yourDate).ToList();
```

This will give you a List Collection.